# What solvents can get rid of oil stains?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, solvents

What kind of solvent would you use to remove an oil based stain?

I need help for a chemistry lab report and I tried to look it up but nothing seems to be helping me

Comment: My suggestion would be to look for dry-cleaning solvents...

Comment: I use lipase to do the job

Answer (score 2):

Depending on where you live different dry-cleaning solvents are indeed the best choice. Perchloroethylene $\ce{Cl2C=CCl2}$ is probably still the easiest one to get.